# Power BI Avg weighted time format measures

Tags: time, powerbi, format, measure, weighted

I have created two measures to calculate my weighted ACW avg but the time format is not showing correctly and I am stuck.  I have an imported table from Postgres into Powerbi the column I am using for my acw time is in seconds in the Inboundlog table.

To get my average I first created a measure to sum the total ACW time.

```
SUM ACW = SUM(inboundlog[time_acwork])
```

I then created a second measure to divide this result by my total handled calls

```
 AVG ACW = DIVIDE([SUM ACW], [Calls Handled])
```

When added to my table it shows the correct results but not in time format. When I added the Format to the AVG ACW meausre for either "HH:MM:SS" or "MM:SS" it throws the results way off. Is there a way I can manipulate to show in time format but with the correct resutls.

Here are the correct results not in time format.

[image: Power BI Results]

This is a screenshot of what I am tying out to.

[image: End Result]

Screenshot of the data type in the inboundlog table.

[Time_acwork](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL1yw.png)

Comment: Please don't us all caps on the internet. It's considered SHOUTING and not polite.

Comment: It would be useful to know the data type of the column `inboundlog[time_acwork]` - Is that a date/time value or a decimaL?? Please show that data in your screenshots, so we can see what you're dealing with. Edit your question to do that. Do not post that in a comment. You can post a comment when you have updated the question, so people following this topic will be notified.

Comment: Thank you I just posted a screenshot of the data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use code from here:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Aggregating-Duration-Time/ba-p/22486

```
Duration = 
// Duration formatting 
// * @konstatinos 1/25/2016
// * Given a number of seconds, returns a format of "hh:mm:ss"
//
// We start with a duration in number of seconds
VAR Duration = [Duration in Seconds]
// There are 3,600 seconds in an hour
VAR Hours =
    INT ( Duration / 3600)
// There are 60 seconds in a minute
VAR Minutes =
    INT ( MOD( Duration - ( Hours * 3600 ),3600 ) / 60)
// Remaining seconds are the remainder of the seconds divided by 60 after subtracting out the hours 
VAR Seconds =
    ROUNDUP(MOD ( MOD( Duration - ( Hours * 3600 ),3600 ), 60 ),0) // We round up here to get a whole number
// These intermediate variables ensure that we have leading zero's concatenated onto single digits
// Hours with leading zeros
VAR H =
    IF ( LEN ( Hours ) = 1, 
        CONCATENATE ( "0", Hours ),
        CONCATENATE ( "", Hours )
      )
// Minutes with leading zeros
VAR M =
    IF (
        LEN ( Minutes ) = 1,
        CONCATENATE ( "0", Minutes ),
        CONCATENATE ( "", Minutes )
    )
// Seconds with leading zeros
VAR S =
    IF (
        LEN ( Seconds ) = 1,
        CONCATENATE ( "0", Seconds ),
        CONCATENATE ( "", Seconds )
    )
// Now return hours, minutes and seconds with leading zeros in the proper format "hh:mm:ss"
RETURN
    CONCATENATE (
        H,
        CONCATENATE ( ":", CONCATENATE ( M, CONCATENATE ( ":", S ) ) )
    )
```